# How can I change the AWS WAF log timestamp type from long(number) to date in AWS Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logging, timestamp, amazon-waf

I am a beginner using AWS WAF, AWS Elasticsearch.

I want to change the AWS WAF log timestamp type from long(number) type to date type.

Because of long type timestamp not working in Kibana visualize and Dashboard time filtering.

I tried to this query code on the AWS ES Dev Tools.

[image]

But, I have just received this message.

[image]

**How can I solve this problem?**

Thanks a lot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Would you show your original index queries? And by trying fixed this issued, you may wanna try `reindex`.

Usage:

```
POST _reindex 
{
  "source": {
     "index": "test-timestamps"
   }, 
  "dest": {
     "index": "test-timestamps-2"
   }
}
```